# Content outside "window" not visible?

Tags: html, css, window, border

I'm trying to make a website with a top border running across, but when the browser window is compressed, and horizontal scroll-bars appear, the border at the top is visible only when the scrollbars is at their original position. If you scroll to the right, the border stops.

HTML code:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='content'>
        As you can see, when the window is small enough for scrolling, the border only exists in the "original" window space.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
* {
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#container {
    border-top:1px solid green;
}
#content {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JS fiddle to show what's happening. (Resize your browser window so a horizontal scrollbar appears on the output window):
http://jsfiddle.net/RL77f/

Answer (score 1):

This is a common behavior when the browser window becomes narrower than the fixed content width. The solution is to add a min-width to the outer container.

```
#container {
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
    overflow: auto;
}
```